# c#, how to read xml inner elements

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file that list a bunch of files that I need to read to generate a `string[]`.
I can identify each ProjectGroup in the xml file:

```
XmlNodeList projectsGroup = doc.SelectNodes("//ProjectGroups/ProjectGroup");
if (projectsGroup != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode projectNode in projectsGroup)
    {
         //Need to read inside the ProjectGroup, how?
    }
}
```

With this code I can create a list of each ProjectGroup.  How can I read inside each Project to have my list of files? 
 Here is the xml file that I am working with:

```
<ProjectGroups>
    <ProjectGroup Name = "InvGroup">
    <Out>
      <Project Name="Inv.Commands" In="false" LC="false">
        <File>Inv.Commands.dll</File>
        <File>Inv.Commands.pdb</File>
        <File>Inv.Commands.xml</File>
      </Project>
      <Project Name="Inv.Common" In="false" LC="false">
        <File>Inv.Common.dll</File>
        <File>Inv.Common.pdb</File>
        <File>Inv.Common.xml</File>
      </Project>
     </Out>
    </ProjectGroup>

    <ProjectGroup Name = "RATGroup">
    <Out>
      <Project Name="DB_RAT" In="false" LC="false" IF="" />
      <Project Name="AnalyzeData" In="false" LC="true" IF="">
        <File>AnalyzeData.dll</File>
        <File>AnalyzeData.pdb</File>
        <File>AnalyzeData.xml</File>
      </Project>
      <Project Name="Commands.GetCh" In="false" LC="true" IF="">
        <File>Commands.GetCh.dll</File>
        <File>Commands.GetCh.pdb</File>
        <File>Commands.GetCh.xml</File>
      </Project>
    </Out>
    </ProjectGroup>
</ProjectGroups>
```

Comment: I appreciate everybody's help.  I tried the first suggestion and it solves my problem. Thanks to all, Tony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the list of project groups, you can select further - not based on the `doc` variable which represents the entire XML document - but based on the `projectNode` that represents a single project:

```
    foreach (XmlNode projectNode in projectsGroup)
    {
         //Need to read inside the ProjectGroup, how?
         XmlNodeList files = projectNode.SelectNodes("//File");

         foreach(XmlNode fileNode in files) 
         {
            // do whatever you need to do to the "file" node here....
         }
    }
```

Comment: You have to use `.//File`. Your XPath pattern will return all File-Nodes in the file.

Comment: Actually, the original answer works better because it iterates through all the projects (XmlNodeList files = projectNode.SelectNodes("Out//Project/File");).  With "//File" I am getting all the files in all the projects without knowing what Project they belong to.

Comment: On the other hand, ".//File" works the same way as ("Out//Project/File").

Answer (score 1):

`projectNode.SelectNodes('.//File')` gives you all `<File>`-Nodes below a single project node. Just iterate over that list and create your array.

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this :

```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load(xmlfilepath);
   XmlNodeList nodes = doc["ProjectGroups"]["ProjectGroup"]["Out"]["Project"].ChildNodes;
   foreach(XmlNode node in nodes ) {
     //do something
   }
```

**EDIT**

If file is really big I strongly recommend use [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx), as XmlDocument loads the file into memory, so it's not convenient to use it with big files.